# Password not getting encrypted while registering a user in Django

Tags: python, django

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        print("user = ",user)
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
            })

# Create your views here.

class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)

# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

The password is not getting encrypted in specified format, and hence the login API is also not working. It shows -
"non_field_errors": [
"Unable to log in with provided credentials."
]
Also, in the admin panel of django, it shows this [invalid password format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq1tP.png)

Comment: are you using AbstractBaseUser

Comment: I think not, where to find this?

Comment: from where are you getting this model User

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
I used this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your "RegisterSerializer" class "create" method.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'])
        user.password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

And don't forget to import make_password method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
```

And you create method is not properly indented.

Serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the same error is still there

Comment: Try:

    `user = User.objects.create_user(
                password=validated_data['password'], username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'])`

    `return user`

Comment: Did you check the indentation of "RegisterSerializer" class "create" method? I think "create" method is not properly indented.

Comment: But in your question serializer.py file is not properly indented. I have updated my answer you can verify it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the password gets encrypted. I thought create method is inside the Meta class.